# How can I refresh part of the webpage and retrieve information again?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wanted to obain real-time USDGBP data from sinajs.cn.
The location (third line of code) returns an array of strings called hq_str_GBPUSD. 
Now the calculation part below can refresh itself every 1 second, that's no problem. But it only calculates the information already obtained. The retieving info part (third line) does not refresh. 
How am I going to fix it and get real time USDGBP data? Thank you.

```
<div id="scores">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w3school.com.cn/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=GBPUSD" charset = "gb2312"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
var $scores = $("#scores");
var elements = hq_str_GBPUSD.split(",");

setInterval(function () {
    var $rateP = (elements[1]/elements[3]-1)*100;
    var $rate = $rateP.toFixed(2);
    $("#scores").text("USDGBP:"+elements[1]+"Change:"+$rate+"%");
    $scores.load("index.php #scores");
    }, 1000);

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `$scores.load("index.php #scores")` do?

Comment: You have the tag; use ajax to get the data, rather than a `script` element.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ajax complains about CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's not a better native way (see their API), you can always reinsert the whole script again and then fetch the modified global variable `hq_str_GBPUSD`:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.src = "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=GBPUSD";
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

Let's try it from a snippet with a simulated timeout:

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
var hq_str_GBPUSD = "not fetched yet";

setInterval(function() {
  res.innerHTML = hq_str_GBPUSD;
  }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  var scr = document.createElement('script');
  scr.src = "http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=GBPUSD";
  document.body.appendChild(scr);
  }, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

It works!

Comment: If I just put your block of code in setTimeOut function in setInterval function, then it will perfectly solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! You also might want to consider cleaning the previous script tags from the DOM when you append a new one (just to make it cleaner).